# How to implement a custom class to have only one instance per value set (not singleton)

Tags: c#, enums, static, constants

I have a custom class as follows with two enumerations:

```
public class MCode
{
    public AEnum A { get; }
    public BEnum B { get; }
    public byte C { get; } 

    //Some constructors and methods
}
```

I'd like to create only one instance of each MCode (never create MCode if one exists with the same 3 values) and then if ever I create an object that contains an MCode as a property, I'd like it ensure it is the same instance as the property of any previous object containing such an MCode.

In terms of numbers:
Number of possible MCodes 100s
Number of references to MCodes at runtime 100s
Number of distinct MCodes in terms of values 3-10.

********************Update***********************************

Now tried to use a Factory class as follows:

```
public static class MakeMCode
{
     private static List<MCode> Instances;

     public static MCode Instance(AEnum ae, Benum be, byte c)
     { 
          var mc = Instances.Find(x=>x.GetHashCode()==MCode.GetHashCode(ae,be,c));

          if (mc == null)
          {
               var newmc = new MCode(ae, be, c);
               Instances.Add(newmc);
               return newmc;
          }
          return mc;
     }

}
```

where I have implemented the required GetHashCode and also a static GetHashCode as suggest below (without the second it seemed I need new MCode in order to determine the HashCode, which was also why I avoided using Instances.Contains)

But now I'm unsure how to implement the constructors in MCode such that it uses the MakeMCode.Instance and protects against any MCodes being created without calling MakeMCode.Instance

Comment: The only way I can think of is to keep a global list/dictionary of instances already created. However, your instances are mutable, and I'm thinking you would need to implement something like copy on write to create a new instance in case one of the properties is modified. Do you really want to do that?

Comment: I see that makes sense, although I will have to refer to it through a global static class. Also I will in effect only have a few elements in the Dictionary, so is that appropriate (when I imagine a Dictionary I think of a long list). I added further info on the numbers

Comment: Maybe you could tweak the Singleton pattern to take arguments in the `GetInstance()` method. There you could decide if you already have a instance with these values and, if so, return it or otherwise create a new one. So in your "Singleton" class you would remember the instances created and there corresponding values. The same functionality could be move in some kind of fabric that decide whether a new instance is required or not. I think then the responsibilities of the two classes would be clear

Comment: @royalTS So the pseudo-singleton would have an internal list of instances and the GetInstance would check this list?

Comment: @gwizardry maybe a dictionary with a hash or something like this (as recommend before) so the look up would be easier. But I think this functionality should be moved to a factory class

Comment: @royalTS Sorry I'm no expert, had to look up FactoryClass but I think I get the idea. So the factory class say 'MakeMCode' contains the list/dictionary and is given the job of creating each MCode...first by checking its own list. So the MCode constructor calls the Factory class MakeMCode and this factory class has Singleton like behaviour.

Comment: @gwizardry nearly, you call the factory whenever you need a new MCode instance and then the factory returns an existing one or creates a new one by using the constructor of MCode

Comment: Added a follow on question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45375273/is-a-private-static-list-an-appropriate-way-of-limiting-the-set-of-instances-of

Answer (score 1):

You can create static List MCodesPool, and add MCodes there on creation. Differ codes by overwriting GethashCode() method like

```
return (byte)AEnum * 256 * 256  +  (byte)BEnum * 256 * C;
```

So, when you construct MCode you can check if your MCodesPool contains MCode with created HashCode.

P.S. Use sorted collections if you plan to create tons of objects.