# Is a private static list an appropriate way of limiting the set of instances of a class

Tags: c#, static, factory, protected

I am trying to avoid multiple instances of a class being created with the same internal data. I tried an implementation with a separate class for building the MCode but trying to protect the MCode constructor did not work so I have come back to this implementation. I wonder if this is good design or what better solution there may be?

```
public class MCode : IEquatable<MCode>
{

    private readonly static List<MCode> Instances;
    public AEnum AE { get; }
    public byte C { get; }
    public BEnum BE { get; }

    public static MCode GetMCode(AEnum ae, BEnum be, byte c)
    {
            if (Instances==null)
            {
                Instances = new List<MCode>();
                var newmc = new MCode(ae, be, c);
                Instances.Add(newmc);
                return newmc;
            }

            var mc = Instances.Find(x => x.Equals(ae, be, c));

            if (mc == null)
            {
                var newmc = new MCode(ae, be, c);
                Instances.Add(newmc);
                return newmc;
            }
            return mc;
    }

    protected MCode(AEnum ae, BEnum be, byte c)
    {
        AE = ae;
        BE = be;
        C = c;
    }

    public new bool Equals(MCode mc)
    {
        return (GetHashCode() == mc.GetHashCode());
    }

    public new bool Equals(AEnum ae, BEnum be, byte c)
    {
        return (GetHashCode() == GetHashCode(ae, be, c));
    }

    public new int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ((byte)AE * 256 * 256 + (byte)BE * 256 * C);
    }

    public static int GetHashCode(AEnum ae, BEnum be, byte c)
    {
        return ((byte)ae * 256 * 256 + (byte)be * 256 * c);
    }
}
```

The motivations for this are that I have multiple instances of classes which contain the same MCode property and I'd like them all to be using the same read-only MCode instance.

Comment: Why do you want to limit the number of instances of the class?  Maybe consider making it a `struct` instead?  Or at least use `HashSet` instead of `List`.

Comment: I wasn't aware  of a HashSet (my C# book is up to .NET 3!)

Comment: `Instances` is `null`, where you instantiate it? To improve existing and working code you can use another [site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Edited to explain the motivations

Comment: That doesn't really explain why.  Are you worried about memory consumption?  How many instances of this class do you expect to create?

Comment: @gwizardry: if you make the list readonly you dont make the `MCode`-instances in it readonly and you also don't avoid that someone adds new instances. But you should really use a `HashSet<MCode>` if you don't want to allow duplicates. Since you have overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode` it works already. But use `overrides` instead of `new`.

Comment: Are you trying to make *enum-like* class? See [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/188205/156546).

Comment: @juharr I'm worried about memory consumption - although not very worried. I could get by with separate instances, I just thought that it would make sense to control the memory and how to do this in this particular case.

Comment: @gwizardry I'd only worry about this if you actually run into memory issues.  Just let .Net handle the memory for you.  As long as you don't create billions of instances that have a very long life time you should find that the memory will be reclaimed when the lifetime of the objects end and the GC runs.

Comment: @Sinatr Yes kind of. I'll read the link. The difference being that MCode can have very many possible values, its just that at run time only a few will be used (of which there'll be very many instances or references to a few instances). I'd like Enum like behaviour though so perhaps your link explains how to achieve this.

Comment: Also you should be overriding `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode` instead of hiding it with `new`.

Comment: @juharr Reading up on HashSet there's no method for finding the instance matching the particular object/hash so not sure how it helps for the GetMCode method.

Comment: @gwizardry Yeah on second thought you'd want either `Dictionary<int, List<MCode>>` where you use the hash code to get a set of MCodes and then search that or just `Dictionary<Tuple<AEnum, BEnum, byte>, MCode>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are describing looks to be a [Flyweight Factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).  Flyweights are classes that are relatively small, and there are a finite number of "unique" objects, so maintaining a catalog of unique instances can help reduce unnecessarily duplicated data in memory.

One example is `US State`.  There are only 50 unique states, so keeping a collection of 50 states as a set of unique instances might make a difference in a system that, say, needs a state for every user record.

I would also separate the class from the factory.  Make the factory a separate class, and make the constructor for `MCode` `internal` (instead of `protected`.

I would also be careful of your `Equals` implementation.  Just because two objects have the same hash code does not mean that they are equal.  It may be true in your case since you have a finite number of objects that can be covered by the `int` space, but it looks weird.  Implementing the *actual* `Equals` logic (which you already have in the list lookup) would also negate the need for the duplicate `GetHashCode` method.

Comment: I'd read briefly about the Factory pattern earlier after a response in my earlier post and tried it like that, so perhaps it was not using internal that scuppered it. Might I ask why a separate Factory class is beneficial? What are the advantages of doing it that way?

Comment: Separation of concerns, mostly.  There's a idiom in OOP that classes should be designed to have one purpose - you have two: storing data and creating objects.  It's not a huge flaw, however.

Comment: Its a little like your example but in fact more global. Say like country regions. But until runtime dont know which country the data records will be from. So you're not going to hardcode all regions of all countries in the world. Instead you're going to let the code populate the regions once you send in data for one country, but you obviously don't want to fill up your memory with a region for every person in the country. Also in my example the number of different MCode is likely 5-10.

Comment: @D Stanley ok thanks that makes sense. A car and a car-mechanic are not the same thing. Got you.

Comment: @D Stanley In response to your edit. What do you mean by the Equals logic? I wanted to avoid for Equals(AEnum ae, BEnum be, byte c) creating a new MCode since I was trying to protect such instance creation (although I accept that such temporary instances should be well handled by the background C# memory management)

Comment: I mean make `Equals` compare the item properties instead of calling `GetHashCode()`.  If you want a helper method that doesn't create an instance that's fine, but try to remove duplicated logic.

Comment: @D Stanley Accepted answer since its more or less got me to the solution. I'm still unsure how I might restrict access to the constructor in the regular MCode class. I used a simple Flyweight pattern to code a builder but I can still create other instances of MCode. Do I need to use an interface implementation of the flyweight pattern?

Comment: @gwizardry an `internal` constructor should work if the factory is in the same assembly (project). The factory could then create `MCode` but nothing outside of the assembly could.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a factory method and a static dictionary:

```
public class MyType
{
    private readonly static Dictionary<int, MyType> instances
       = new Dictionary<int, MyType>();

    public static MyType CreateNew(int id)
    {
        if (instances.TryGetValue(id, out var instance)
            return instance;

        return new MyType(id);
    }

    private MyType(int id) { ... }

    public int UniqueId { get; }
}
```

If your unique identifier is something more complex than an `int`, I'd simply implement a private nested struct/class with value equality semantics and use that as the dictionary's key.

Comment: There isn't an id in play here the OP is going to have two `Enum` values and a `byte` for the lookup.

Comment: @juharr I'm conveying the idea, the exact unique identifier can be anything.